# SQL Injection with Semgrep/Spotbugs

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, spotbugs, sast, semgrep

For SAST checks in our CI pipeline we use Semgrep and SpotBugs scanners. This scanner finds the following situation as an instance of SQL Injection.

Repository Class

```
        Query q = em.createNativeQuery(FIND_PRODUCTS_BY_IDENTIFER);
        q.setParameter("productidentifier", productIdentifierParam);
```

The FIND_PRODUCTS_BY_IDENTIFER is in a separate class and is defined as a constant

public static final String FIND_PRODUCTS_BY_IDENTIFER= "SELECT PRODUCTID FROM PRODUCT WHERE ID in (:productidentifier)";

The Query is parameterized and is not a case of SQL Injection and is a false positive. Can anyone throw some light on what has to be changed to make this violation go away (or) is this already a known Bug with Semgrep analyzer.

[image]